# set open ssl issuer (iss)

Tags: php, openssl, jwt

1. I generate private.key with:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048.
```

2. From private key I generate public key with:

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -pubout -out public.key
```

3. With these keys oauth2 server creates authorization JWT

And I need that JWT payload contains issuer (iss).

On which step should I add it? And any ideas how to add it?

Comment: I don't understand how creating a keypair with openssl is related to setting a certain claim in a JWT. How do you create the JWT?

Comment: @jps probably it should be set on key generating. I'm doing it with this one: https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/installation/

Comment: the issuer claim refers to the issuer of the token ([the principal that issued the JWT](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.1)). That's has usually nothing to do with key generation.